# не работают @media при уменьшении окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт https://recode.monster , при уменьшении окна медиа-запросы не работают и верстка едет, но при этом в панели разработчика и на устройствах устройства все отлично работает. пробовал разные viewport, ничего не помогает[image: пример]

Answer (score 1):

Без кода, можно предположить, что у Вас отсутствует:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Добавьте его между тегами `<head></head>` и проверьте.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Ваши медиа-запросы некорректно написаны - вместо `max-device-width`надо писать просто `max-width`, иначе такой запрос только на девайсах и будет отрабатывать.

Вот пример с `max-device-width` - при простом уменьшении ширины экрана работать не будет:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 30px;
}

@media (max-device-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```

А вот тот же пример, но с `max-width` - совсем другое дело:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```